# R How to return several data frames as output from foreach loops

Tags: r, dataframe, foreach, return

I'm trying to parallize the below simulation I'm running with foreach, but am struggling with combining the results into a meaningful data structure.

What I want to do (or how I did without parallelization):
1. Create 4 data frames to store my results in:
2. Run my simulation loop (e.g. 100 times) and in each loop I store the results into the respective rows of my 4 data frames.

Example code:

```
sim_n = 10

sim_power = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=sim_n, ncol=8))
sim_rank  = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=sim_n, ncol=8))
sim_mean  = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=sim_n, ncol=8))
sim_base  = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=sim_n, ncol=8))

for (i in 1:sim_n)
{
 # Here I'm doing sth. different in reality, so take this just as an example
 sim_power[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_rank[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_mean[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_base[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
}
```

After I did the loop, I have my 4 nice data frames and all is good.

Now trying to do this with foreach, i'm not sure how to set this up. I basically did more or less the same, just changing the loop to:

```
test = foreach (i =1:sim_n) %dopar%
{
 # Here I'm doing sth. different in reality, so take this just as an example
 sim_power[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_rank[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_mean[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_base[i,] = runif(8, 1, 10)
}
```

But it obviously doesn't work. I googled and found that I probably have to create my own output function, but I really don't know how to do that.

Note: before the foreach loop, I added all the relevant parallelization initialization, so that works fine.

**UPDATE**:

If I do the following, I *believe* I get the results as a list of lists, but then again, I'm not sure how to restructure this to get 4 data frames.

```
test = foreach (i =1:sim_n) %dopar%
{
 # Here I'm doing sth. different in reality, so take this just as an example
 sim_power = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_rank = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_mean = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_base = runif(8, 1, 10)

 return(list(sim_power, sim_rank, sim_mean, sim_base))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list is a good idea. You can use `parLapply` also that gives you directly a list. You can do the following, taking what you already did:

```
test = foreach (i =1:sim_n) &dopar%
{
 # Here I'm doing sth. different in reality, so take this just as an example
 sim_power = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_rank = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_mean = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_base = runif(8, 1, 10)

 return(list(sim_power, sim_rank, sim_mean, sim_base))
}

library(data.table)

sim_power <- rbindlist(lapply(test,function(x){x[[1]]}))
sim_rank <- rbindlist(lapply(test,function(x){x[[2]]}))
sim_mean <- rbindlist(lapply(test,function(x){x[[3]]}))
sim_base <- rbindlist(lapply(test,function(x){x[[4]]}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, your code gives me the following error: Error in rbindlist(lapply(test, function(x) { : 
  Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list

Answer (score 1):

With the help of denis and further googling the error I got, I think I found a solution. Not sure if it's the most elegant or fastest way, but it seems to work:

```
test = foreach (i =1:sim_n) %dopar%
{
 # Here I'm doing sth. different in reality, so take this just as an example
 sim_power = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_rank = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_mean = runif(8, 1, 10)
 sim_base = runif(8, 1, 10)

 return(list(sim_power, sim_rank, sim_mean, sim_base))
}

sim_power = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(test,function(x){x[[1]]})))
sim_rank  = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(test,function(x){x[[2]]})))
sim_mean  = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(test,function(x){x[[3]]})))
sim_base  = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(test,function(x){x[[4]]})))
```